# Converting number to decimal when given both

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns: `price` and `dec`. As shown in this sample dataframe:

```
price  dec
505    2
300    2
680    3
100    2
```

What I'd like to do is make another column that takes the price and decimal and then converts it like so:

```
price  dec  realprice
505    2    5.05
300    2    3.00
680    3    .680
100    2    1.00
```

How do I make a function that does this?

Comment: why 2nd row not 3.00?

Comment: @bakka Sorry just fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `div` with `**`

```
df.price.div(10**df.dec)
Out[510]: 
0    5.05
1    3.00
2    0.68
3    1.00
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the columns and use powers of `10`:

```
df['realprice'] = df['price']/(10**df['dec'])
```

Yields:

```
   price  dec  realprice
0    505    2       5.05
1    300    2       3.00
2    680    3       0.68
3    100    2       1.00
```